# Is there anyway to remove persian/arabic numbers from <input type="number" /> or <input type="tel" /> in mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm trying to remove the ability to input persian/arabic numbers with mobile phones. Specifically (١٢٣) button in iOS. any hint is appreciated.

I have already tried the pattern="[0-9]*" and pattern="\d*" but both show the persian numbers.

I don't want to convert numbers. I just want to remove 123 icon in iOS tel keyboard.

P.S: I`M NOT USING jQuery

Comment: Why does that matter? You can still get the right number with `element.valueAsNumber`.

Comment: Just handle on key (down ? ) press events. Test, and if not `/^[0-9]*$/` in the edit box, replace using this `/[^0-9]+/` with "" nothing. Try not to use anything complex.

Comment: @SebastianSimon can you give an example?

Comment: There are solutions without jquery listed in the duplicate links.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am trying to understand is there anyway to remove 123 icon in iOS or not. I am not trying to convert digits.

Comment: So why did you try to set `pattern` attribute with regex that only enforces on submit and not as-you-type validation?

Comment: patterns changed the keyboard from (numbers and characters) to (numbers) in iOS. so I was asking for some patterns (if it exists) to remove ١٢٣. thats why this is not a duplicate question!

Comment: With `pattern` attribute, you can't remove anything, it only validates the input on form submit.